# What's the kernel option to disable the kernel bootlogs appearing on the serial port?

Tags: kernel, embedded

I have an embedded device where uboot is passing the kernel command line options to set the serial port.
I want to disable the kernel bootlogs appearing on the serial port. I can't change uboot or kernel command line parameters what's the option in kernel config to 
disable the bootlogs appearing on the serial port? I am thinking of early_printk to disable the kernel boot logs. Is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should change `CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT` from the default of 7 to a lower value.

If you add the `quiet` boot option, the console log level is set to the value of `CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_QUIET`, which is normally 4. So as you said you cannot change boot options, changing `CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT` to 4 or lower should achieve the same effect.